# In Azure how to mount bootable image to Linux VM?

Tags: azure

We need to upgrade our SuSe Linux 11 SP4 to 12 SP4.In VSphere we mounted ISO to Linux VM and restarted the VM Guest OS and able to upgrade OS with on screen instructions. Not sure how to do it the same when Linux machine is on Azure.We have ISO Images which we need to mount.

Comment: You don't. Azure doesn't work that way. You make new virtual machines instead.

Answer (score 1):

Azure doesn't boot ISOs. Create a new SLES 12 VM and migrate the data over, repoint data disks to the new instance or restore backups.

If you cannot abandon your OS install, you can download the VHD, boot it in a local hypervisor, and do what you need to. But that seems like a lot of download and upload time.